# Java Looping Constructs and the OCAJ7 Study Guide

Tags: java, oracle, for-loop, foreach

I'm preparing to take the Oracle Java SE7 Associate Exam, and I'm confused by this sample question from the study guide:

---

Given the following declaration of an array, which statement will display
each element of the array?

`int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`

a. `for(int n : arr[]) { System.out.println(n); }`

b. `for(int n : arr) { System.out.println(n); }`

c.`for(int n=1; n < 6; n++) { System.out.println(arr[n]);}`

d. `for(int n=1; n <= 5; n++) { System.out.println(arr[n]);}`

---

The answer key gives b, c, and d as correct answers.  However, it seems to me that only b should be correct because both c and d will begin indexing the array at arr[1] instead of arr[0].

Is this a mistake in the answer key?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think that is a mistake...

Answer (score 1):

B is the only one that looks right to me.

C & D both start from 1 (not 0), and if my counting is right would throw and index out of bounds exception.

I think it is a mistake in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking deviously, like the writers of the exam, C & D would at least display 4 elements in the array, but then would get an exception.  So they still don't satisfy the requirements.